# How can I convert the NSString to a array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, nsarray

For example, I read a data like this

```
a\tbcd\tttte\tjjjd\tnjnjnjd\tss\tee
```

and I want to make a array like this:

```
{ @"a", @"bcd", @"ttte", @"jjjd", @"njnjnjd", @"ss", @"ee" }
```

How can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `-componentsSeparatedByString:`, as in

```
NSArray *ary = [mystring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

> componentsSeparatedByString: Returns
>   an array containing substrings from
>   the receiver that have been divided by
>   a given separator.
>
> - (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString
>     *)separator Parameters separator The separator string. Return Value An
>     NSArray object containing substrings
>     from the receiver that have been
>     divided by separator.
>
> Discussion The substrings in the array
>   appear in the order they did in the
>   receiver. Adjacent occurrences of the
>   separator string produce empty strings
>   in the result. Similarly, if the
>   string begins or ends with the
>   separator, the first or last
>   substring, respectively, is empty. For
>   example, this code fragment:

```
 NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
 NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

> ```
> produces an array { @"Norman",@"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }.
> ```
>
> If list begins with a comma and
>   space—for example, ", Norman, Stanley,
>   Fletcher"—the array has these
>   contents: { @"", @"Norman",
>   @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }
>
> If list has no separators—for example,
>   "Norman"—the array contains the string
>   itself, in this case { @"Norman" }.
>
> Availability Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.
>
> See Also:
>
> componentsJoinedByString: (NSArray)
>
> – pathComponents
>
> Related Sample Code:
>
> ColorMatching
>
> CoreRecipes
>
> iSpend
>
> iSpendPlugin
>
> QTKitMovieShuffler
>
> Declared In NSString.h

From [NSString docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a)