# Objective C-Adding data from a Key Value of Dictionary in an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

how to store[ rcImage = "1475004450741343.jpg,1475004451955166.jpg" ] to an array from a dic.

```
    {
        id = 24;
        rcImage = "1475004450741343.jpg,1475004451955166.jpg";
        registrationNumber = RJ01;
        registrationdate = "2015-09-28 00:00:00.0";
        regno = RJ01;
    }
```

these are my codes.

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            imageArray=[paramData objectForKey:@"imageRC"];
            NSLog(@"%@",imageArray);
```

Please help ?

Comment: You need image full url not 1475004450741343.jpg this type

Comment: If you store these image in your project, using dataWithContentsOfFile instead. If not , sure you add full URL, not just image name.

Comment: @nynohu Sir my focus is to save those two images in an array rest is easy i will do it Please guide me through it .

Comment: @YogendraGirase sir I have eddited the post please Help and in any case i have to fiest save that url in an array so how to do it ?

Comment: you want store image names in Array ?

Comment: @YogendraGirase Sir I am fetching these images from Rest api now to display them like this must be in a url or somthing how to do it any idea ?

Comment: @HarshitGoel Please show the response of your Rest api?

Comment: You can use this and display image through URL -->https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @YogendraGirase Thanks Sir !! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You use this code**

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *imageString = [paramData objectForKey:@"rcImage"];
NSLog(@"--%@",imageString);
imageArray = [imageString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"--%@",imageArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you only want to convert your rcImage to array, here is all you need.
[How can I convert the NSString to a array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814130/how-can-i-convert-the-nsstring-to-a-array)

Comment: Sir I am fetching these images from Rest api now to display them like this must be in a url or somthing how to do it any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

```
NSString *strImageArray = [paramData objectForKey:@"rcImage"];
NSArray *arrImages = [strImageArray componentsSeperatedByString:@","];
```

You will get array of your image.

Comment: Thanks Sir !! It helped :)